# QDateTime не определяет шаблон

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется два шаблона:

```
const QString yearFormat = "MMM dd yyyy";
const QString timeFormat = "MMM dd hh:mm";
```

и код, их использующий:

```
QString data = getText();
auto date = data.indexOf(":") != -1 ? QDateTime::fromString(data, timeFormat) :
                    QDateTime::fromString(data, yearFormat);
```

`getText()` возвращает строки вида "Jan 29 2013" или "Dec 24 11:35", но QDateTime их не хочет парсить, `date.toString()` возвращает пустую строку

Comment: Так а вы проверяли, что у вас содержится в `data`? Откуда сведения про содержимое `data`: вы это сами проверили или это "как должно быть в теории"?

Comment: `qDebug() << data` выводит нужные строчки, с этим все хорошо. Решение в первом ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен на 100% но, попробуйте добавить скобки:

```
QString data = getText();
auto date = (data.indexOf(":") != -1) ? QDateTime::fromString(data, timeFormat) :
                QDateTime::fromString(data, yearFormat);
```

Дополнено: все таки дело не приоритете, на сколько я понимаю, QDateTime::fromString использует локаль по-умолчанию. Вам необходимо принудительно указать какую локаль успользовать:

```
QLocale l(QLocale::English);
QDateTime dt = l.toDateTime("Jan 29 2013", yearFormat);

qDebug() << "Dt:" << dt.toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Дает вывод:

```
Dt: "29.01.2013"
```

Comment: Дело не в приоритетах, вызов `QDateTime::fromString(data, timeFormat)` отдельно дает тот же рузельтат